# How to break up a string or command across multiple lines

Tags: vimrc

I am trying to mark up some various common SQL keywords, and here is what I have...on one line:

```
autocmd Syntax * syn match pythonSql       /\v<(SELECT|INSERT INTO|UPDATE|ON DUPLICATE KEY|FROM|WHERE|JOIN|INNER|OUTER|LEFT|RIGHT|ORDER BY|AND|IN|NOT IN|ON|USING|ORDER BY|LIMIT|OFFSET|CONCAT|COALESCE|ALTER TABLE|DISTINCT|OR|AND|IS NULL|NULL|GROUP BY|UNION|ALL|CASE|WHEN|THEN|IF|IFNULL)\ze\s/ containedin=.*String
```

What would be the correct/most legible way to write this? How can one break up commands onto multiple lines? And how could someone break up a string into multiple units or lines?

Comment: See `:h line-continuation`. No special syntax for breaking up strings, except concatenating them and `:execute`-ing target command.

Comment: @Matt I see -- how would you suggest writing out the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `:source`-ing VimScript file there's `:h line-continuation` support (unless `&cpoptions` contains `C`, which is **NOT** the default).

If the code still looks ugly, try to `:execute` the concatenated string:

```
let l:myargs = [
    \ 'arg1',
    \ 'arg2',
    ...
\ ]

execute 'command-name' join(l:myargs) 'more-args'
```

Sometimes also helps `:h printf()` and `:h string()`